# Postgresql row-level encryption

Tags: postgresql, encryption

[Looking over the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/encryption-options.html), I didn't see any mention of row-level encryption.

Lets assume I have a database of highly classified information that needs to get locked down. How can I implement a table with row-level encryption in postgres? Failing row-level, what's the next best thing I can do, and what are the drawbacks?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with row-level encryption? For joins, etc. to work PostgreSQL needs to see the key columns. You can very well encrypt the data columns though (if the inter-table relations are not so secret)

Comment: Not that it would make a difference in this case, but you are linking to the PostgreSQL 8.0 documentation, which is more than 6 years old.

Comment: What do you mean by "row-level encryption"?

Comment: @Jack Douglas http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098(SQL.100).aspx#_Toc189384682

Answer (score 5):

Usually, [you don't want to do this](http://www.pgcon.org/2009/schedule/attachments/129_Encrypted%20PostgreSQL.pdf). Have you given second thoughts to this?

Else, pg_crypto is your friend. But as the above-mentioned slides suggest, it isn't necessarily a panacea.

Answer (score 4):

Things that come to my mind:

1. use the contrib module [pgcrypto](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html) to encrypt the column contents manually (will require a change to your application)
2. Store the data on an encrypted volume/partition (this can be done on table level using tablespaces that are located on the encrypted volume)

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably be better off encrypting and decrypting the data in the application tier not in the database directly.  All you need to do at that point it make sure that the database columns are wide enough to support the new longer values.

Not to be a sales pitch, but I talk about the concepts in Chapter 2 of my book [Securing SQL Server](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1597496251).  There's sample code in the book for .NET on how to encrypt and decrypt data.  If you aren't using .NET the samples won't be of much use, but the concepts will be the same.